# koala gem(Graph API) InvalidURIError while retrieving pages of results with get_page method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm using Koala gem: https://github.com/arsduo/koala to retrieve pages of results from the facebook graph API.

[Edit] I construct the @graph object as follows:

```
@facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
@graph = @facebook.get_connection(..)
```

After fetching the data from facebook, I get a list of results.

I get the next_page_params like this:

```
next_page = @graph.next_page_params
```

Which looks something like:

```
[\"v2.6/496090827168552/members\", {\"fields\"=>\"about,age_range,bio,cover,devices,email,education,first_name,gender,hometown,id,interested_in,last_name,languages,link,location,middle_name,name,political,picture.type(large),relationship_status,religion,work,website\", \"limit\"=>\"30\", \"icon_size\"=>\"16\", \"access_token\"=>\"EAAIeQOKC6YjJE3GUvyHqakVaIZCF1MY4jo5YtQ0qt2DFNPRa3O6akOXUMdx9eOozAFSOIZD\", \"offset\"=>\"30\", \"__after_id\"=>\"enc_AdACS2GnjoUp9fYXSa8maRmdCZAYMNRR7fqHpQG\"}]
```

Now I'm fetching the next page of the result using:

```
@graph.get_page(next_page)
```

This is the error i get:

```
`URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): [%22v2.6/496090827168552/members%22,%20%7B%22fields%22=%3E%22about,age_range,bio,cover,devices,email,education,first_name,gender,hometown,id,interested_in,last_name,languages,link,location,middle_name,name,political,picture.type(large),relationship_status,religion,work,website%22,%20%22limit%22=%3E%2230%22,%20%22icon_size%22=%3E%2216%22,%20%22access_token%22=%3E%22CqXUMdx9eOozAHJl2cS4czacDnIwvEB96RCb1FSOIZD%22,%20%22offset%22=%3E%2230%22,%20%22__after_id%22=%3E%22enc_AdACS2GCCpmD1SFiHnmP0lpr0yiW8maRmdCZAYMNRR7fqHpQG%22%7D]`
```

Comment: How do you construct the `@graph` object? It seems that you are calling `next_page_params` on the wrong object.

Comment: What API request are you trying to browse? I.e. members of what are you trying to list?

Comment: @BoraMa Thanks, it's for Group members. With facebook Api < v2.3. You still have user_groups permission, so you can get a list of members of a group provided the user with the token is a member of the group.

Comment: I see, it seems that you have not explicitly specified the old API version, because the response is of version 2.6. Does something like `Koala.config.api_version = "v2.2"` help? As documented in [this README section](https://github.com/arsduo/koala#graph-api) - see the code examples there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem may be here

```
@facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
@graph = @facebook.get_connection(..)
```

On the github page, it says to call `get_connection` directly with @graph but you are setting @graph to the return value of `@facebook.get_connection(..)`. Rather change it to

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
@graph.get_connection(..)
```

Source: https://github.com/arsduo/koala#graph-api

Comment: This is essentially what the OP is doing. Just that he is storing the API instance in '@facebook', rather than '@graph'. But ultimately he is calling get_connection on the API object itself ('@facebook' in his case), and then storing the response in a '@graph' object. Your suggestion seems to just change the variable name, but won't have any effect as such.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here:

1. Your 'next_page_params' response seems to be a string, while it should have been an array. Are you sure that's the response you are getting ? This could be causing an error when the method tries to convert it into a URI to be parsed. Hence the parsing errors.You could try to use `eval(next_page)` to convert it into an actual array (note: eval is considered unsafe).
2. Which version of koala are you using? In the latest (v2.3.0), get_page method is available only on the API object(`@facebook` in your case), and not on the connection object (`@graph`). Hence, you would use:

   @facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
   @graph = @facebook.get_connection(..)
   next_page = @graph.next_page_params 
   @facebook.get_page(next_page)
3. You could also try calling the next page directly, without first fetching the params like :

   @facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
   @graph = @facebook.get_connection(..)
   @graph.next_page

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is like others have already mentioned. You might get confused with `@graph`, `@facebook` and `results`.

Below is how I implement using Rails to get a list of user's Facebook friends.

```
controller/feeds_controller.rb
def do_sth_with_facebook_friends
 facebook = Facebook.new(current_user)
 facebook_friends = facebook.friends(params[:next_page])
 ...
 @next_page = facebook_friends.next_page_params
 //@next_page will be used as params[:next_page] when you send another request to load the next page
 ...
end

lib/facebook.rb
def initialize(user)
 @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user.facebook_token)
end
def friends(page)
 page ? @graph.get_page(page) : @graph.get_connections('me', 'friends')
end
```

Hope this helps.